# Add a debian source for APT in Kali Linux

Tags: debian, kali-linux

I am trying to add a Debian source for apt:

```
add-apt-repository 'http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main'
```

but I got this message:

```
Error: could not find a distribution template for Kali/kali-rolling
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding repositories to your Kali setup is [not recommended](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories) and liable to break your system. Kali [isn’t a general-purpose distribution](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/what-is-kali-linux), and shouldn’t be used as such; nor [is it intended for non-experts](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux) (and the fact that you’re asking this question suggests you aren’t).

Furthermore, Debian Sid is currently somewhat broken since it’s [undergoing a Perl transition](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2018/10/msg00006.html).

In summary: don’t do this.